# Determine final width of chart area

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts

I have multiple chart areas on a chart, and am trying to set the width for columns (column charts) based on the number of columns.  However, chart area width changes with the number of chart areas on a chart.  So, for example, if there are two columns of chart areas, setting the column width based on dividing the chart width by number of columns in one chart does not work, as the column width now needs to be 1/2 of what is calculated.

Is there a way to find the width of a chart area after the final panel of chart areas has been automatically arranged?

The syntax used for determining column width is:

```
Dim columnwidth As Integer = CInt(chart1.Width / myNumIntervals)
chart1.Series(i)("PixelPointWidth") = columnwidth.ToString
```

Comment: Couldn't you count the data points in your underlying data you're building the chart from?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will determine column width automatically in Column charts, based on the number of chart areas in the final chart.  However, I learned the rule that's used by the compiler for determining the number of columns of chart areas, which is found by using

```
                Dim columnWidth As Integer
                Dim numCols As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(numAreas)))
                columnWidth = 90 / numCols
                chart1.Series(i)("PixelPointWidth") = columnwidth.ToString
```

Thus, the number of columns of chart areas shown in the final chart is equal to Floor(Sqrt(#numAreas)).  If there's one column of chart areas, a width of "90" (it's a string) looked okay.  When two columns of chart areas appeared, a width of 45 seemed good (45=90/2).  So the rule is to simply divide 90 by the calculated number of columns of chart areas in the final chart.